# I want to copy all the text from a webpage and paste it to an word file. I am using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code

```
 import webbrowser as web
 from selenium import webdriver 
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 import time
 import pyautogui
 import os
 import pyperclip
 import docx


 chrome_path = 'C:/Users/Jeet/Desktop/chromedriver.exe'
 custom_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 prefs = {
          "translate_whitelists": {"uk":"en"},
          "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
          }
 custom_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=custom_options)
 driver.get('https://zakupki.com.ua/tender/10019981')
 time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "c")

os.system("start " + "demo.docx")

time.sleep(5)
a = pyperclip.paste()
pyautogui.typewrite(a)
time.sleep(5)}
```

This code is running but text is not copying properly in word file. what can be done to copy specific text (From Result to Customer Information) from the above given webpage

Comment: You need to show your attempts and explain a specific issue that you have

Comment: Hello Yevhen I have updated my issue with the code. can you please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyautogui

import os
import time
import pyperclip

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()
        
driver.get(
    "https://www.facebook.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"a")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"c")

os.system("start " + "test.docx")

time.sleep(5)


a = pyperclip.paste()

pyautogui.typewrite(a)
time.sleep(5)
```

you can use pyperclip to get the clipboard content , os to open a text.docx and pyautogui to paste it

**Note:** make sure you have a file called test.docx in current directory

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: Hello @PDHide I have updated my problem with the code can you please see and let me know if you have any suggestion. I have given the link of the webpage I want to copy specific text (From Result to Customer Information) from the above given webpage.

Comment: try a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '[class="row content-tender"]').text

Comment: I have tried this driver.find_element_by_css_selector( '[class="row content-tender"]').text but same its not in the same format. Is there any other technique.

Comment: if you have any idea about paste option in word like now its pasting in word in text format But I want to paste (keep source formatting (k)) it is available in paste option word.